# How below bean setter and getter generated

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I found below code which is used for generating setter and getter of the bean. this is not clear to me can any one please explain this and its working. I am aware of working of map struct for mapping.

```
@Value.Modifiable
@Value.Immutable
@Value.Style(
    get = {"get*", "is*"},
    init = "set*",
    create = "new",
    beanFriendlyModifiables = true,
    validationMethod = Value.Style.ValidationMethod.VALIDATION_API)
public interface MyAction {

  @NotNull
  @Size(max = 30)
  @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
  String getMyCompanyId();
}
```

Comment: Can you include the imports for the annotations please?

Comment: sure will update found this https://immutables.github.io/ help full.

Comment: import org.immutables.value.Value;
this is the import statement for the above annotations

Comment: There's a [guide](https://immutables.github.io/immutable.html) available by your link. It explain how that library works.